# duplicate os x night shift settings exactly/approximately for linux/ubuntu night light

Tags: night-light

Is there anyway to replicate exactly the mac os x "night shift" temperature settings for night light/redshift?
Fiddled a lot with the temperature bar, but never comes close to the appearance of mac os x night shift.

Night light always looks very red no matter what temperature. I would like to know if it's possible to exactly replicate the night shift settings in linux/ubuntu.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details... If you're not happy with the *night light* tool you're using; use another one (they've been around 5+ years so aren't new)

Comment: You have to check both [RedShift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) and [F.lux](https://justgetflux.com/linux.html). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: mac os night shift only adjust 1 to 100. they don't give rgb levels, so it is not possible to find out just by this. they have billion $$ budgets to whatever settings they came up with is much more asthetically pleasing than default night light settings.
so somebody will have to dig into the mac night light code, or compare screenshots side by side to find settings that exactly match.